# How to define map in yml with key and null value?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a requirement to use a `Map<String, Object>` in yml property, but to allow entering key in the map with null value.

For example:

**application.yml**

```
....
init-services:
  sample-service-discovery:
    port: 8761
    profiles: dev,prod
  sample-config-server:
    port: 8888
    profiles: dev, test
  sample-activation-service:
  some-other-service:
    port: 1234
....
```

`init-services` is a `Map<String, ServiceProperties>`.

`ServiceProperties` is just a POJO with `Integer port, List<String> profiles`.

It compiles fine for the first 2 entries, but on the `sample-activation-service` I get `Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type PathProperties$ServiceProperties` exception.

Question: is there any way to allow having an entry in the .yml map that only has a key but null value is null ? I need to iterate over the keys later, even if their values are null.

Comment: You can have a key that is `null` YAML, but that makes it a non string scalar. Are you sure you want "String key with a null value" that looks like a contradictio in terminis to me.

Comment: I don't want a null key, I want a null value for a key. So that if in the code I do: `map.get("sample-activation-service")` it returns `null`. If my phrasing wasn't clear enough, I'm open to suggestions / edits. I edited the question in attempt to make it clearer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to generate that using Java. but `{null: 1, True: x, x: 42}` is valid YAML. Of course you can only have one `null` key in any mapping as the keys of a mapping have to be unique.

Comment: As I've said in my previous comment, I'm looking for a null value, not a null key. The `sample-activation-service:` in my yaml file is the key, that's supposed to have an object as a value, but I'd like that value to simply be empty, or null. Currently, at least with Spring Boot, that doesn't work. If the yaml tag on my question is misleading, I'll remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work around this issue by adding a constructor to `ServiceProperties` that takes a String as a parameter, and calls the default constructor.

```
public ServiceProperties(String empty) {this();}
```